# How to modify a website to be mobile-friendly using only a CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, cross-browser

I've developed a website that features some JavaScript (one page uses it for popup pictures in an image gallery, another uses a coupon code textfield).  I want to create a CSS stylesheet that will let me adapt everything in the website for a more fluid and simple appearance when it shows up in a mobile browser.  Is there a way to do this with just a stylesheet marked for mobile browsers and if so, what's the formatting?

Also, does having JavaScript on a mobile version of my site pose an issue or can I adapt that to mobile, too?

Comment: Look up 'media queries' for the css side. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

[Here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries) is a good article to get you started

Comment: I've heard about media queries.  I'll give that a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer will be pretty beginner, but have you ever looked about jquery mobile?

There is a lot of html5 usage on it, for simple exaples/projects it wokrs very well.

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: This might be closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cant use CSS for this level of conditional... But you can use Javascript to select specific CSS...

I'm using this library to do this

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

It redirect mobile users to a subfolder on your domain..